# Can I write a program in binary directly ? How can I get the computer to execute it?

Tags: binary

I know that may seem weird and looking for troubles but I think experiencing what the ancient programmers experienced before is something interesting. So how can I execute a program written only in binary? (Suppose that I know what I am doing and not using assembly of course.)

I just want to write a series of bits like `111010111010101010101` and execute that. So how can I do that?

Comment: You won't be able to execute `111010111010101010101`. You have a syntax error on the second bit. ;)

Comment: I think you can't instead make use of some programming language and compiler or write a batch file.

Comment: A hex editor would *kinda work*. There won't be any comfortable option though... programming in assembly is already a bitch, have fun without mnemonics.

Comment: There is no value to writing software this way or learning to write software this way.

Comment: @meagar Except it's fun to interact directly with the lowest-possible-level parts of a computer. I mean, you could argue that there's no point to write bootloader/kernel code because perfectly good code already exists. But there is a point, and that's learning. Regardless of how much difference it'll actually make in any real-life scenario, it's a great learning experience. For example, I wrote a programming language just so it could have a crappier syntax than Lisp, and I gained extensive knowledge about interpreters. It's all about gaining knowledge.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use a hex editor. You'll need to find out the relevant executable format for your operating system, of course - assuming you want to *use* an operating system... I suppose you could always write your own bootloader and just run the code directly that way, if you want to get all hardcore.

I don't think you'll *really* be experiencing what programmers experienced back then though - for one thing, you won't be using punch cards, paper tape etc. For another, your context is completely different - you know what computers are like *now*, so it'll feel painfully primitive to you... whereas back then, it would have been bleeding edge and exciting just on those grounds.

Comment: What about programming with just transistors and switches?

Comment: What about programming by using a magnetized needle on your disk?

Answer (score 18):

Use a hex editor, write your bits and save it as an executable file (either just with the file extension `.exe` in Windows or with `chmod a+x filename` in Linux).

The problem is: You'd also have to write all the OS-specific stuff in binary format, and you'll have to have a table that translates from assembler code to binary stuff.

Why not, if you want to experience low-level programming, give D.E. Knuth's assembler MMIX a try?

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on the platform you are using. But that's sort of irrelevant based on your proposed purpose. The earliest programmers of modern computers as you think of them did *not* program in binary -- they programmed in assembly.

You will learn nothing trying to program in binary for a specific Operating System and specific CPU type using a hex editor.

If you want to find out how pre-assembly programmers worked (with plain binary data), look up [Punch Cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card).

.

Answer (score 6):

Use a hex editor to create your file, be sure to use a format that the loader of your respective OS understands and then double click it.

Answer (score 4):

most assemblers (MMIX assembler for instance see www.mmix.cs.hm.edu) dont care if
you write instructions or data.

So instead of wirting

```
Main ADD $0,$0,3
     SUB $1,$0,4
     ...
```

you can write

```
Main TETRA #21000003
     TETRA #25010004
     ...
```

So this way you can assemble your program by hand and then have the assembler transform it in a form the loader needs. Then you execute it. Normaly you use hex notatition not binary because keeping track of so many digits is difficult. You can also use decimal, but the charts that tell you which instructions have which codes are typically in hex notation.

Good luck! I had to do things like this when I started programming computers. Everybody was glad to have an assembler or even a compiler then.
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Or he is just writing some malicious code.
I've seen some funny methods that use a AVR as a keyboard emulator, open some simple text editor, write the code that's in the AVR eeprom memory, and pipe it to "debug" (in windows systems), and run it. It's a good way to escape some restrictions too ;)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with writing malicious code, so long as you attempt it only on yourself or other willing subjects. I’m no security expert, but I’m pretty sure this is one of the encouraged ways of learning what bad programming and project management choices lead to potential exploits. You can’t prevent exploits if you don’t know (at least in theory) how to exploit things.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that by interacting directly with hardware you could write in binary. To flip the proper binary bits, you could use a magnetized needle on your disk drive. Or butterflies.

[image]